# JavaScript/jQuery encapsulated variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, highcharts, encapsulation

In highcharts' [tooltip.pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat), we see an example of JavaScript encapsulated variables: we can pass something like `'blah {series.name} blah {point.y}'`, and that's changed to something like `'blah '+series.name+' blah '+point.y` internally.

I'd like to make a similar functionality in a jQuery plugin I'm building. Is there a standard way to do this?

I thought of checking all possible encapsulated variables, but that wouldn't be that neat, would it?

Comment: **Note**: I didn't know how you'd call such behaviour, feel free to edit a correct term in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard way that I know of but regex + reduce seems like a good combo:

```
function format(str, obj) {
  return str.replace(/\{([\w.]+)\}/g, function(_,key) {
    return key.split('.').reduce(function(a,b){ return a[b]; },obj);
  });
}

var obj = { series: { name:'myseries', id:40 }, point: { x:1, y:2 } };
var str = 'blah {series.name} blah {point.y}';

console.log(format(str, obj)); //=> blah myseries blah 2
```

Comment: Works :) I'll wait to see if there's a standard way - if not, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "standard way". I mean you're just parsing a string with a custom format, each library does it their own way I guess. This is definitely the shortest way AFAIK.

Comment: Perhaps jQuery had a function for it, like they have `$.extend` for options.

Comment: There was this long time ago, but it's not updated anymore, https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl. The term you're looking for is "templates" you can find many libraries here http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/